# How many DBMS's can be installed on a single server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle

The software in our organization uses various databases, many on different database platforms.

Can we put all the various database platforms on a single machine?  What are the limitations to this?

Should we have a single machine for each DBMS type?  What are the limits to the number of database per DBMS in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate.

SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 et al typically do not play nicely alongside other "server" software. They tend to monopolise system resources, particularly memory, so while you *could* install them side-by-side, you won't be getting the best from them. It would also be challenging to diagnose performance issues with two different DBMS's competing for resources.

Given a collection of ageing or little used applications that required a mix of database systems, virtualisation would be a tempting solution to consolidate.

Answer (score 0):

Now that virtualization is common and accessible there are no factors that I can think of that would force a business to put all their databases on one server. I see cases where there is more than one Oracle database in use on the same server but if you are talking Oracle and MSSQL and MySQl all on one server this constitutes a single point of failure.

Comment: In the case of Oracle the license policy towards non-oracle virtualization will make many businesses think twice. In most cases you'll have to pay licenses for the underlying hardware, not per vCPU.